# Unable to connect WebApp private endpoint from pipeline (AzurePowershell@5 task)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Problem description:
I have Azure WebApp with staging deployment slot (configured to use private endpoint). In Azure Devops before swapping slots I am trying to perform custom healthcheck suing "Invoke-WebRequest" from ps1 script.
I have custom agent pool which has firewall rule defined to be able to reach webapp via private endpoint.
When script is running in a pipeline request with 200 resultcode is visible in appInsights, however script enters the catch block. I tried to log exception and I saw only empty line.
When I am trying script from local machine connected to VPN script is working fine. Is there any specific setting for private link connection I might be missing?

Script is defined as separate AzurePowershell@5 task

Comment: Based on my understanding of your issue description, you may be referring to this scenario that is outlined in this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/deploy-app-service-with-private-endpoint-enabled-via-azure/ba-p/3789370)

When the private endpoint is enabled and public traffic is denied to the web app, all the public traffic to this app is cut off. Since there is a range of IP addresses where agents are deployed, they have a public IP. 


As a solution, you may either allow the IP ranges list in the firewall or use self-hosted agents to deploy.

Comment: Switching AzurePowershell@5 to AzureCli@2 resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update. To benefit the community, I'll summarize our discussion as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following-up from the comments to summarize the discussion.

@gerwaz fixed the issue by switching AzurePowershell@5 to AzureCli@2.

Additionally, when the private endpoint is enabled and public traffic is denied to the web app, all the public traffic to this app is cut off. Since there is a range of IP addresses where agents are deployed, they have a public IP. As a solution, you may either allow the IP ranges list in the firewall or use self-hosted agents to deploy.

Reference: [Deploy app service with private endpoint enabled via Azure DevOps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/deploy-app-service-with-private-endpoint-enabled-via-azure/ba-p/3789370)